# Better way to run pipe command using apache commons exec

Tags: java, arp, apache-commons-exec

I am using apache commons exec to run command: `arp | wc -l`
Below is my code:

```
 private String runCommand(String cmd, String params) {
        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(cmd);
        commandLine.addArguments(params);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PumpStreamHandler pumpStreamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout, stderr);
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(30000);  // 30s timeout
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setStreamHandler(pumpStreamHandler);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);

        try {
            int retCode = executor.execute(commandLine);
            System.out.println("Executed '" + cmd + "'\n"
                    + "returnCode: " + retCode + "\n"
                    + "stdout:\n" + stdout.toString() + "\n"
                    + "stderr:\n" + stderr.toString());

            if (retCode == 0) {
                return stdout.toString();
            } else {
                throw new NonZeroExitStatusReturnedException(commandLine.toString(), retCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not run command "+ commandLine.toString(), e);
        }
}
```

Here the cmd is `/bin/sh` and params are `-c arp|wc-l`
The code is giving following output:

```
Executed '/bin/sh'
returnCode: 0
stdout:
       54       71       4321

stderr:
usage: arp [-n] [-i interface] hostname
       arp [-n] [-i interface] [-l] -a
       arp -d hostname [pub] [ifscope interface]
       arp -d [-i interface] -a
       arp -s hostname ether_addr [temp] [reject] [blackhole] [pub [only]] [ifscope interface]
       arp -S hostname ether_addr [temp] [reject] [blackhole] [pub [only]] [ifscope interface]
       arp -f filename
```

I have two questions here:
**Question 1**. I cannot understand that why there are three numbers in my output (54       71       4321). Isnt it supposed to be only one number?

**Question2**. Is there any better way to run the same command using apache commons exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation carefully - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/CommandLine.html.
Here's the answer for Question2:

```
private String runCommand(String cmd, String[] params) {
        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(cmd);
        commandLine.addArguments(params, false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PumpStreamHandler pumpStreamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout, stderr);
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(30000);  // 30s timeout
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setStreamHandler(pumpStreamHandler);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);

        try {
            int retCode = executor.execute(commandLine);
            System.out.println("Executed '" + cmd + "'\n"
                    + "returnCode: " + retCode + "\n"
                    + "stdout:\n" + stdout.toString() + "\n"
                    + "stderr:\n" + stderr.toString());

            if (retCode == 0) {
                return stdout.toString();
            } else {
                throw new NonZeroExitStatusReturnedException(commandLine.toString(), retCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not run command "+ commandLine.toString(), e);
        }
}
```

Here cmd is: `/bin/sh`
params is: `new String[] { "-c", "arp|wc -l" }`

Comment: Would be nice, if you would note the difference between your problem and your solution code: `commandLine.addArgument(params, false);` 
Because it is really hard to get the difference otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, I built a pure Java solution:

```
/**
Run command $cmd1 and pipe its STDOUT to $cmd2, just like executing:

$ cmd1 | cmd2

from a Linux shell
*/
private String runCommand(String cmd1, String[] params1, 
                          String cmd2, String[] params2) {

    PipedOutputStream stdin = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream stdout = new PipedInputStream();
    // - pipe STDOUT of first process to STDIN of second process
    stdin.connect(stdout);

    // - First process: arp
    CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(cmd1).addArgument(params1);

    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(stdin));
    executor.execute(commandLine, new DefaultExecuteResultHandler());

    // - Second process: wc
    CommandLine commandLine2 = new CommandLine(cmd2).addArguments(params2);

    DefaultExecutor executor2 = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor2.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(System.out, System.err,
                                                     stdout));
    executor2.execute(commandLine2, new DefaultExecuteResultHandler());
}
```

This omits the need for the pipe ('|'), which will enhance the portability and security (it makes it easier to perform sanitization checks) of your code.